# Find if the homography matrix is good

Tags: opencv, matrix, homography

I found [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2588/check-if-homography-is-good/) code at OpenCV forum and it works fine and can detect bad homographies. But I can't find the theory behind it.

Could anyone explain the full theory?

Code:

```
bool niceHomography(Mat HM)
{
    const double det = HM.at<double>(0, 0) * HM.at<double>(1, 1) - HM.at<double>(1, 0) * HM.at<double>(0, 1);
    if (det < 0)
        return false;

    const double N1 = sqrt(HM.at<double>(0, 0) * HM.at<double>(0, 0) + HM.at<double>(1, 0) * HM.at<double>(1, 0));
    if (N1 > 4 || N1 < 0.1)
        return false;

    const double N2 = sqrt(HM.at<double>(0, 1) * HM.at<double>(0, 1) + HM.at<double>(1, 1) * HM.at<double>(1, 1));
    if (N2 > 4 || N2 < 0.1)
        return false;

    const double N3 = sqrt(HM.at<double>(2, 0) * HM.at<double>(2, 0) + HM.at<double>(2, 1) * HM.at<double>(2, 1));
    if (N3 > 0.002)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: take a look at [here](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/issues/11)

Comment: thanks, but I still can't get the lines where N1,N2,N3 appears
- if I am right N1,N2 point to scale and he limited scale between 0.1 to 4
I have no clues